# Authenticating user with LDAP from PHP with only sudo user and Password?

Tags: php, ldap

How can I authenticate from PHP using LDAP with the sudo user and Password?

I found simple php script which authenticate user as follow, but I have nosudo users and sudo users in my ldap database.

This script authenticate all users sudo as well as nosudo users,I want only sudo users able to login. So can you please suggest modification?

**Php script**

```
// get username and password from form


$username = $_POST['username'];


$password = $_POST['password'];
/*
   * checks the credentials against the LDAP server
   * $user - myBYU
   * $pass - password
*/



 function authenticate($user,$pass){

  // prevents guest account access
  if($pass == ""){
     return false;
  }

  try{

     $Yldap_location = "ldap://ldap.byu.edu";
     $ldap_port = 389;

     // call the ldap connect function
     $Ydatabase = ldap_connect($Yldap_location, $ldap_port);

     // bind the connection
     $good = @ldap_bind($Ydatabase, "uid=".$user.",ou=People,o=BYU.edu", $pass);

     if($good){
        // valid credentials
        return true;
     }
     else{
        // invalid credentials
        return false;
     }

  }
  catch(Exception $e){
     return false;
  }


 }

   // call authenticate function



if(authenticate($username,$password)){
  // authenticate successful

     // set session
     $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "true";

     // redirect
     echo $_SESSION['loggedin'];
     $url = "http://orca.byu.edu/iacuc/".$_SESSION['url'];
     header("Location: ".$url);
}


else{

  // authenticate fails

     // redirect to login
     header("Location: http://orca.byu.edu/iacuc/Login.php");


}




**Sudo User Ldif is**
dn: uid=rupesh,ou=example,dc=example,dc=com

cn: Rupesh Jeevanrao Shewalkar

gidnumber: 502

homedirectory: /home/rupesh

loginshell: /bin/bash

mail: rupesh.shewalkar@example.com

mobile: 99999999

objectclass: extensibleObject

objectclass: posixAccount

objectclass: top

objectclass: shadowAccount

objectclass: sudoRole

shadowlastchange: 16148

shadowmax: 99999

shadowmin: 0

shadowwarning: 7

sudocommand: ALL

sudohost: ALL

sudooption: logfile=/var/log/sudo.log

sudooption: timestamp_timeout=5

sudooption: ignore_local_sudoers

sudooption: !env_reset

sudooption: log_year

sudooption: log_host

sudooption: insults

sudouser: rupesh

uid: rupesh

uidnumber: 2164

userpassword: welcome123

------------------------------


**Non sudo user LDIF:**


dn: uid=contactus,ou=example,dc=example,dc=com

cn: contactus

gidnumber: 502

homedirectory: /home/contactus

loginshell: /bin/bash

mail: Contact.Us@example.com

objectclass: extensibleObject

objectclass: posixAccount

objectclass: top

objectclass: shadowAccount

objectclass: sudoRole

shadowlastchange: 15621

shadowmax: 99999

shadowmin: 0

shadowwarning: 7

uid: contactus

uidnumber: 2108

userpassword:welcome@123
```

Comment: How can you distinguish the sudo-User from the nonsudo-Users in the LDAP? There is an objectclass "sudoRole" which Could be used but it is assigned to both users so it seems to be useless.

Comment: I will remove sudorole from nonsudo user but can you help me how to code in php

Answer (score 0):

I'd first do an LDAP-Search for a user with the given uid that also has the attribute `objectclass` set to **sudorole**. When no result is returned, eitehr the username has been wrong or the user is not a sudoer.

When you have a result, you can use that results `dn` to check the provided password. I have a complete code-example prepared at https://gist.github.com/heiglandreas/5689592.

You will have to adapt the filter in line 38 from `objectclass=posixAccount` to `objectclass=sudorole`.

Hope that helps